# Wi-fi stopped working

Tags: wi-fi, troubleshooting

The other day out of the blue my Wi-Fi stopped working. I've tried fixes I found here in stack exchange (see below), but nothing seems to work. How can I tell if it's a hardware problem or a software problem?

I should note that the Wi-Fi says it's on but dose not show any SSID's and my network history's are no longer there. I have tried...

- deleting the `data/misc/WiFi` folder the rebooting
- Fxr fix and rescue

I have a sprint galaxy S3 rooted running Cyan fox 2.02 (KitKat 4.4.2)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! What are the "fixes" you've tried? If you don't want to get the same stuff recommended, it might be helpful to [edit] your question and include those details ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've just applied some formatting to make it more obvious. Have to pass the answer to someone else, though. Just one more thing: Did the "out of the blue" go together with some app you've installed/updated? Not that I've heard of such side-effects, but that's usually one the first things suspected.

Comment: Actually i did install and un install this app --->     https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easy.battery.saver      around  the time i noticed that Wi-Fi was gone

Comment: Try booting your device in [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) and see whether your problem persists. Contact the author of that app and ask him for advice; it might be connected (some "optimizing" might have stuck though the app was uninstalled).

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere it works fine in safe mode.....so hardware isn't the issue

Comment: Exactly. That is a relatively clear sign some "user-space app" is the culprit. So you just need to figure out which one it is. Trouble is, you cannot easily "disable" them, only uninstall. As you're on 4.x already: Use [Helium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.koushikdutta.backup) (or `adb backup`) to backup all of your apps ***separately*** (including `.apk` *and* data). Then uninstall them one by one. As soon as it starts working again, you've found the troublemaker – and can restore all *other* apps+data from that backup. Please report back then :)

Comment: Did the one by one uninstall but it did not fix it self.... So I cleaned the cache and the dalvik cache and wiped data. Wi-Fi works now.

Comment: Glad to read! I've summed it all up in my answer below. Consider "accepting" the answer (by clicking the check-mark next to it), so other users see it's solved. Enjoy your now-again-working device!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can have multiple reasons. First thing to look for is always whether a "user app" might have caused this. This can be done by booting into [safe-mode](/questions/tagged/safe-mode): if everything works here, at least the hardware is fine, and the system as well. In that case, next steps would be:

- Boot into [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode), and clear (wipe) cache. This is possible on rooted and unrooted devices, each recovery (stock or custom) should permit this (exceptions are quite rare). Then reboot, and see if the issue is solved.
- If it's not solved, and your device is equipped with a custom recovery: Again boot into recovery, this time wipe the "Dalvik Cache". Reboot, and check whether the issue is solved now.

If none of these two steps brought you any relief, you need to go the "hard way":

- Backup all your apps into single backups (so you can restore them separate), including `.apk` and data. Useful tools for that: `adb backup` (see: [adb](/questions/tagged/adb), [backup](/questions/tagged/backup)) and [Helium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.koushikdutta.backup), or on rooted devices also [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).
- Uninstall apps in reverse order of their installation (the culprit it's more likely an app you've installed lately, than an app you've installed a year ago) one-by-one, and after each single uninstall see whether the problem solved. Doesn't hurt to reboot as well (i.e. uninstall→reboot→check, next).
- At the point where it starts working again, re-install all apps you've removed (again one-by-one), skipping the last one – as that was most likely causing the issue.

---

If the issue still persists (or still persisted in safe-mode), last resort is a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset). Before doing that, make sure your contacts etc. are either synced with your Google account, or backed up otherwise (the apps you have already "secured" with above steps). Does the issue stay even after this, it's most likely a hardware issue, and you'll have to turn in your device for service.

If, on the other hand, the factory-reset made it working again, *carefully* restore from your backups – again one by one, with a reboot in between (to make sure you don't end up where you've started).